# Printing in Java Swing Components

Tags: java, swing, printing

I have class `PrintUtilities`, which has the following method to print JPanel and its sub components:

`public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex)`

There is JLabel within the JPanel, which is right justified and the problem is the printed copy is chopping last digit in the JLabel. I can justify it to Center and the printing works but I don't want to change how it is displayed on the screen.

So, is there a way that I tell the class to display it one way and print it another way? I tried paint(Graphics g) but it will effect the painting the component on the screen.

In short I want to define a way to print JLabel printer without affecting it looks and layout on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing a border around the JPanel to see if the entire panel gets cut somehow.

Previously, I had a similiar experience and it turned out that my paper size didn't match that in the printer.

Failing that, you might need to investigate scaling your output just a bit so that it fits on the page.

Hope that helps,
Ewald

Comment: There are some more labels to the right of that particular label and they showing fine. The only difference in the clipped label is right justified.

Comment: Perhaps a code example might help if you haven't gotten it right yet?